# Calling a middleware function in Xamarin Android Binding

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, middleware

I'm trying to call one function to set the value of a private field in a class inside my jar file. The jar file is used to create Xamarin Android binding.

My question is: is there a way to call a function or set the value of a private field behind the scenes in a Xamarin Android binding without user interference?

Comment: If the jar file is used to create Xamarin Android binding, after referencing it to your project, the jar file has been wrapped with c#, and then you can use reflection to set the value of a private. Why not? Or maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Reflection means that the user would have to interfere in the process. I meant if it was possible to do it somehow during the bindings are created where the user sees no changes.

Comment: Attribute + Reflection.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: It works like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), you need add annotation, and use Reflection to read the annotation, so users don't need interfere it, is it right?

Comment: I know what you mean but that means it would be hardcoded in the original Java code. I want to have a middleware in the sense that neither the original java code nor the Xamarin C# code has any changes.

I ended up making some bash magic to literally modify Java code before compilation and then revert it back. Not the best way but it works :)

I'll close this issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making some bash magic to literally modify Java code before compilation and then revert it back. Not the best way but it works :)

Closing this.